# Is it possible to lint code without changing git history for the lines?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Git blame and such are really helpful. In VS Code, for example, for every line, I can see who wrote it, and when. This comes in handy when you're upgrading the codebase and want to know if a bug is due to this code, and you see oh, this was written 3 years ago and bug is recent so therefore it's likely this is fine.

Linting is messing this up.

It'd be useful if there was a git which recorded changes in code, not just text characters. Imagine git + typescript engine. This way git would still remember who wrote the code even if someone ends up changing the formatting for every line and such as long as the code is exactly the same. (If you minify the code, without changing variable names, then code is still the same, as far as compiling is concerned.)

Comment: "Linting" merely diagnoses problems. I'm guessing you are talking about code reformatting?

Comment: Linting also have autofix option but yes linting/autoformatting is what i'm referring to. for example linter would change double quotes to single in a way that doesn't break the code. formatter may align variables all in one column and  = symbols in another columns etc. lot of changes in text but none even semantically speaking